# Simple open-source solution for PDF document storage and search-based retrieval

Tags: open-source, document-management

I am involved with a very small residential management company which has a lot of documents that I want to digitise into PDF and put on the web for all residents to access. Many people are not technical, so something simple to use is essential.

I have the skills to set up a server based LAMP-based solution, albeit one that should not cost significant amounts of money to purchase or maintain, hence open-source, preferrably with a small memory footprint. Everything I have looked at so far though (such as Alfresco, KnowledgeTree and LogicalDOC) seem like major overkill, and complex both in terms of setup and for users.

I was thinking along the lines of something like AjaxExplorer, which seems to do the file browsing part of what I want to do admirably. In terms of full-text searching, is there a product that will work with AjaxExplorer, or something else that can work alongside it, that people would recommend as a relatively easy to configure tool for indexing and subsequently searching a document repository?

It would be acceptable to have separate areas of the front-end for browsing the file tree, and simple searching by filename / metadata and full text search, if, as I suspect, there is no suitable integrated solution.

Comment: What is the format of the files you wish to search?  That will likely be the biggest factor in finding your search tool.

Comment: Mainly PDF - I'll edit the question

Comment: You may want to look at CMS systems.  For example, I know someone that uses Plone for this purpose. I think it has a module for full-text PDF.

Comment: Thanks for the answers - not sure that they're exactly what I'm looking for. I may just use http://swish-e.org/ as an indexer as it seems pretty simple and capable.

Comment: If you are using PDF as in "PDF file output for scanned paper documents", you might need [OCR to run over the data first](http://blog.konradvoelkel.de/2010/01/linux-ocr-and-pdf-problem-solved/) for indexing purposes.

Comment: There is a linux tool called pdftotext (if memory serves).  I know for small deployments I've seen scripts run this and then just do a grep. Also there is a pdfgrep too floating about.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would just use a regular distrobution of Apache (without PHP) and then add a filter  to serve just the .pdf documents:

There are many different ways you could do this.  For example, this directive that you place within your "Directory" node in your httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory "C:/Apache2.2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes Includes MultiViews
    IndexOptions +ScanHTMLTitles -IconsAreLinks FancyIndexing FoldersFirst NameWidth=*
    AddIcon (IMG,/webicons/image3.gif) .gif .png .jpeg .jpg .xbm .PNG .JPG .GIF .tiff .bmp
    AddIcon (IMG,/webicons/compressed.gif) .7z .zip .cab .tar .jar .mdb .ldf .mdf .CAB
    AddIcon (IMG,/webicons/binary.gif) .exe .msi .rdp .pcf .dia .class .ks .keystore .scc
    AddIcon (IMG,/webicons/a.gif) .txt .log .properties .doc .xls .xml .ts .msg .dat .sql .csv .pem .sh .py .tlp .java .der .csr .key .crt .bat .cmd .inf
    AddIcon (IMG,/webicons/link.gif) .lnk .htm .url .URL
    AddIcon (IMG,/webicons/pdf.gif) .pdf
    AddIcon /webicons/folder.png ^^DIRECTORY^^
    #ForceType application/octet-stream
    ....
    ....
```

Then type: http://domain.com/pdf/blah.pdf

If you really must have a search feature, you could install PHP and use [PHP flat file search](http://www.niblr.com/php-flat-file-search-script/) .

Answer (score 1):

I have used MNOGOsearch for indexing a pile of PDF files. It do full text searches of PDF's and many other document types. You may also find the search front end quite familiar.

The *nix versions are GNU licensed.

http://www.mnogosearch.org/

Comment: Cool software but it should be noted that beyond 3,000 documents, it costs around $1000 for a license.

Comment: Never pushed that many documents before, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

[ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/) is an open-source solution for storing files that can run on LAMP.  It has a [very clean interface](http://demo.owncloud.org/index.php/apps/files), and while it has other features (calendar, contacts, music, pictures), [they can all be easily disabled](http://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=10133).  As of [version 3](http://owncloud.org/owncloud-3-release/) it has an integrated PDF viewer. As of [version 5](http://owncloud.org/the-new-owncloud-5-features/), it has full-text PDF searching powered by Lucene.